# Why does the search box allow to search with more than 5 tags?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

Questions can only have 5 tags or less so why does the search box allow you to search for more than 5 tags?

The search functionality is working based on an `AND` condition. So as per the logic there is nothing to show while searching with more than 5 tags. Then why does the search box allow to search with more than 5 tags? It should be restricted.

Comment: No, because you can do `[c++] or [haskell] or [vba] or [javascript] or [prolog] or [r] or [matlab]`. It is kind of useless to limit upfront what a user can enter.

Comment: You mean you dont want to search for questions having a tag from _among_ a collection of tags?

Comment: @rene You said **Tag search does an AND causing not a single question to match as questions can only have 5 tags. Returning an empty result is by design**  in my previous question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359323/all-questions-functionality-looks-like-working-wrong?noredirect=1#comment531916_359323. That's why am asking it. Can you explain briefly with an answer( the search is working with (AND) or (OR) or (AND and OR) condition)?

Comment: No thanks, that is perfectly explained in the various questions here on meta, and/or MSE and/or in the help center about how search works. I have better things to do.

Comment: You can see all search capabilities https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Answer (score 10):

Considering the search box is a regular text field for obvious reasons, even if OR searching of tags was not supported (which it *is*), I'm not sure how you'd even be able to enforce such a limit mechanically for AND searches the same way you can with the Tags field in the question editor.

And since OR searching of tags *is* in fact supported, that question becomes altogether moot.

Comment: If user using  AND for more than 5 tags sequentially. then we should restrict it.

Comment: You don't get to decide if it is `AND` or `OR`. That is decided in the query. If you want the `AND` or `OR` option feature implemented, then that is a different matter completely...

Comment: @Script47 according to the help document  https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching **OR operator**:    *To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": [widgets] or [geegaws] returns questions tagged with either tag*

Comment: @RameshRajendran _why do we need to restrict?_ if user uses AND with more than 5 tags, there would simply be no results..

Comment: @SurajRao But we know it already. then we should restrict in frontend. Why we need a service call for it? because **we know the result will be an empty**

Comment: @RameshRajendran: What it, in the future, we support only 4 tags? Then SE would _also_ have to edit the search validation. ___Don't fix what ain't broken___.